# Help understanding Sampling rate, ODR and oversampling of BMP390

Tags: sampling, sensing, oversampling

I'm trying to understand how fast I can measure pressure changes with the [Bosch BMP390 sensor](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bmp390-ds002.pdf), but there are a few parameters in the datasheet that are confusing me and I would like to understand how these parameters work.

From the first image below, I get that the maximum sampling rate would be 200Hz, meaning that the fastest it can take 1 sample is 5ms.

Questions:

1. Why doesn't the measurement time increase linearly based on the number of samples configured via oversampling?

**Possible explanation:** Taking 2 isolated samples would take 5ms*2, due to the overhead of powering and processing the samples, but if it is done via oversampling, the overhead is reduced since it is like chaining multiple samples under one sequence of powering up the circuitry.

2. Based on 1, why as the number of samples increases via oversampling, it takes even less time per sample?
3. How does ODR relate to all this, is it just a way to specify how many isolated (individual) samples I want to perform and read from the sensor?

So for example, odr_sel = 0x0B, the sensor will be outputting 1 sample every 5 ms for 10.24s for a total of 2048 samples taken?

---

[image: Sampling rate BMP390]
*Table 1: Sampling rate BMP390*

---

[image: Measurement time BMP390]
*Table 2: Measurement time BMP390*

---

[image: ODR BMP390]
*Table 3: ODR BMP390*

---

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same questions. Do you figure out the answers?